# Deserialize JSON with ObjectId function to Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to parse json string to `Map<String, Object>`

my code is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
.......
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() { };
                this.map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, ref);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("cannot create Map from json", e);
            }
```

the example of json is:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("595cc3e6cbaa230d3c764649"),
    "type" : "msg",
    "quantity" : 472,
    "price" : 15.04
}
```

But the result is:

```
cannot create Map from json
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'ObjectId': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: {
  "_id" : ObjectId("598ac67fcbaa23254498df87"),
```

I have many json strings with ObjectId. And I do not want change text.

I do not know names of all fields, so I need Map. I could not use POJO object.

How to parse json with ObjectId funstion to `Map<String, Object>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I use org.bson.Document.

```
import org.bson.Document;
.........
Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString);
return new HashMap<>(doc);
```

And the last question: Why jackson could not parse as bson Document?

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because the _id value does not follow the JSON standard (see [JSON.org](http://www.json.org)). JSON values can only be: a number, a String, an array, an object (starting with '{' and ending with '}'), 'true', 'false' or 'null'. See JSON.org for more information. Your JSON appears to be a BSON (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).

**Edit:**

A rather hacky solution but maybe just replacing the parts of the BSON that are invalid for JSON works for you?:

```
String jsonString = "{
                      \"_id\" : ObjectId(\"595cc3e6cbaa230d3c764649\"),
                      \"type\" : \"msg\",
                      \"quantity\" : 472,
                      \"price\" : 15.04
                      }";

jsonString.replace("ObjectId(","").replace(")","")
```

Of course you would have to replace all invalid entries.

Comment: I know. I need solution for this incorrect JSON. It generated by RoboMongo and RoboMongo has processed it.

Answer (score 0):

It is so because your `JSON`is not valid as per [JSON Syntax.](http://www.json.org/)

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("595cc3e6cbaa230d3c764649"),
"type" : "msg",
"quantity" : 472,
"price" : 15.04
}
```

is not a valid `JSON`.

```
Error: Parse error on line 2:
{   "_id": ObjectId("595cc3e6cb
 -----------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

validate your `JSON`from [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I know that json not valid. I use Intellij IDEA and it shows it. But this JSON generated by RoboMongo and I shoud use it in my test.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is remove the {"_id" : ObjectId("595cc3e6cbaa230d3c764649")} from your json if its not important and do what you were doing.

```
Document  doc = (Document) DataDao.findOne("Id");

doc.remove("_id");
final JsonWriterSettings settings = JsonWriterSettings.builder().outputMode(JsonMode.SHELL).build();
String json = doc.toJson(settings);
XyzData xyzData = jsonHelper.fromJson(json, XyzData.class);
```